# I am looking for a dictionary which would explain word "dauem"

Tags: dictionary

I've met an exercise:

Wie lange - die Führung im Museum - dauem

I have to build a question of these parts. I know the sense of dauem.

Wie lange dauert die Führung im Museum?

It means to last, but I cannot find any information on the Internet about dauem form. 
Is it a typo? Everywhere Dauern word is used but not dauem.
German words could have a lot of suffixes where are the tables describing all possible combinations?

Comment: The question is based on a typo.

Comment: Yeah - it is [dauern](http://www.canoo.net/inflection/dauern:V:haben:Dauer_haben). Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the font used by this site there is virtually no difference between "m" and "r+n".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that should be a typo or you might have read it incorrectly.

I think the word you mean is *dauern* with *r* and *n* at the end.

It is a verb of the noun *Dauer*.

Comment: It is a verb, not an adjective.

Comment: Whoops yeah you are right of course.